# Display won't turn off, Turns black Instead Lenovo ThinkPad W540

Tags: windows, power-management, laptop-display, lenovo-laptop

In my power setting, my display should turn off after a minute, when this amount of time elapses, the display is still on but showing black screen instead of turning off.
How Can I solve this?
Details:
Lenovo ThinkPad W540
Windows 8.1 Pro with WMC
legacy Boot

Comment: Have you gone to *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options*, *Change plan settings*, *Change advanced power settings*,  and adjusted the separate *Sleep* and *Display* timeout options?

Comment: Yes I have, no difference

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my display drivers, I uninstalled them and reinstalled from vendor websites. Issue solved.